# Random password generator: many, in columns, on command line, in Linux

Tags: unix, passwords, shell, passwd

A while back, I came across a random password generator for the command line that displayed a grid of "memorable" passwords. Output was something like this:

```
adam@host:~$ CantRememberThisCommand
lkajsdf   aksjdfl
kqwrupo   qwerpoi
qwerklw   zxlkelq
```

The idea was that you could run this utility while someone was looking over your shoulder, and still pick a password with some level of secrecy due to the large number of choices.

I cannot remember what this utility was called. Oh interwebs, can you help?

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, but Steve Gibson has something like this available online at https://www.grc.com/ppp.htm

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`pwgen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen).

[image]

There are also some interesting ways to do this [without installing additional software](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Security/password_generator.htm), but the 5-letter command is a bit easier to remember :)

Comment: You're more than welcome :)

Comment: I keep coming back to this page because roughly every 6 months I need to generate a password but forget the command! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No need to install extra packages as OpenSSL should be installed on most machines. we can use the following code to generate an random password:

```
openssl rand -base64 10
```

Comment: This is very handy, but strictly speaking taking random bytes and encoding them as base64 string does not necessarily mean a random string. E.g. all 10 char passwords generated like this will end in '=' (because of padding). Also the only other non alpha numeric characters included in these are + and /, which may not be optimal.

Comment: Use a value that is a multiple of 3 (e.g. `openssl rand -base64 12`) and there will be no trailing `=` or `==`.

Comment: add `alias newpass="openssl rand -base64 12"` to shell config ie. _~/.zshrc_ for quick generation of random strings with `newpass` command

Answer (score 4):

According to your example output `pwgen` is a good guess (see the answer of John T). But there are many [such tools available](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/password.htm):

- [pwgen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen) - generate pronounceable passwords
- [gpw](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/gpw.1.html) - program to generate pronounceable passwords
- [apg](http://linux.die.net/man/1/apg) - generates several random passwords

Also password managers such as [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/) provide a passwort generator (but it does not focus on commandline usage nor on pronouncable passwords).

Answer (score 0):

Check out deepsix at http://ericandresen.me/technology/deepsix/ It is cross-platform developed in C and works on every platform I have tested it on, macOS, x86 & 64-bit Windows, and Linux. Just as you describe it offers -cNumber of Chars and -iIterations and at present offers uppercase, lowercase and numeric symbols.