# What command line tool can generate passwords on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, password-generation

I am looking for something that has an usage like

```
passgen <length> <charset>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Cross-Platform: Using PERL

There's a [PERL password generator](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Security-Systems/PERL-Password-Generator-46301.html) that works for Windows, *nix, OS X, etc.

```
Usage: genpass [-OPTIONS] LENGTH
-s, --symbols       Exclude symbol characters.
-n, --numbers       Exclude number characters.
-u, --uppercase     Exclude uppercase characters.
-l, --lowercase     Exclude lowercase characters.
```

On Windows, check the other answers.

#### Unix/Linux

See answers of this question: [Random password generator: many, in columns, on command line, in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/109224/random-password-generator-many-in-columns-on-command-line-in-linux)

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.009/lib/pp.pm, converts a perl script to an executable. So problem solved.

Comment: @johnthexiii Oh, nice. I added it to the answer for later reference.

Comment: [`net user administrator /random`](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/setting-windows-xp-user-account-with-random-password/) needs to run under elevated mode on Vista and up

Comment: **Warning** `net user administrator /random` **resets** password for administrator.

Comment: Please add the warning to the answer.

Comment: Please remove the Windows part of the answer!

Comment: @PythoNic I removed it based on your edit, I guess people find it objectionable despite a warning being there.

Answer (score 10):

Depends on how strong you want your password to be. Of course if security is not a concern then `echo %random%%random%` in cmd or [`Get-Random -Minimum 100000000`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random?view=powershell-7) in PowerShell will just work

With PowerShell you have another better option: call [`GeneratePassword(int length, int numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Security_Membership_GeneratePassword_System_Int32_System_Int32_). For example to generated a 12-character long password with at least 3 special symbols you can call it like this

```powershell
# Just need to call once at the start of the script
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")

[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(12, 3)
```

There are several MS TechNet blog posts on this:

- [Generating a New Password with Windows PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/generating-a-new-password-with-windows-powershell/)
- [How to Generate a Secure Random Password using PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2011/08/04/how-to-generate-a-secure-random-password-using-powershell/)
- [PowerShell Random Password Generator](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/undocumentedfeatures/2016/09/20/powershell-random-password-generator/)

In case you don't want to work with PowerShell then [here's a pure batch solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34802042/995714)

---

.NET Core does not support System.Web.dll so it [doesn't have `[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53307844/995714) and you'll have to write a custom a password generator or find some available code on the internet. Here's one in [Password generation in PowerShell Core (6+)](https://dev.to/onlyann/user-password-generation-in-powershell-core-1g91)

```powershell
$symbols = '!@#$%^&*'.ToCharArray()
$characterList = 'a'..'z' + 'A'..'Z' + '0'..'9' + $symbols
function GeneratePassword {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateRange(12, 256)]
        [int] 
        $length = 14
    )
    
    do {
        $password = ""
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $length; $i++) {
            $randomIndex = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::GetInt32(0, $characterList.Length)
            $password += $characterList[$randomIndex]
        }

        [int]$hasLowerChar = $password -cmatch '[a-z]'
        [int]$hasUpperChar = $password -cmatch '[A-Z]'
        [int]$hasDigit = $password -match '[0-9]'
        [int]$hasSymbol = $password.IndexOfAny($symbols) -ne -1

    }
    until (($hasLowerChar + $hasUpperChar + $hasDigit + $hasSymbol) -ge 3)
    
    $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText
}
```

See also

- https://gist.github.com/Jaykul/5cb0410abd40672707faf67549404ea8
- https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/01/13/generate-random-password-using-powershell/

You can also [install the password generator module](https://andreilungu.com/powershell-random-password-generator/)

```powershell
$ModuleName = "RandomPasswordGenerator"
Get-Module -Name $ModuleName -ListAvailable | Uninstall-Module
Install-Module $ModuleName -Force -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: I found another batch solution, that is even close to be readable by sane humans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629694/make-a-random-string-in-batch/30630254#30630254

Comment: @GrasDouble with the other batch file you can tune what type of characters you want to go into the password. Your linked question is about alphanumeric characters only. Of course it can be made to produce non-alphanumeric letters but it's not as flexible as the other question

Comment: +1 This answer works with PowerShell.  It does not work with PowerShell Core.

Comment: @MarkIannucci that's because PowerShell Core doesn't support System.Web.dll. Luckily there are many well-written solutions for it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SecurePassword Kit [command line password generator](https://web.archive.org/web/20160320090124/http://www.getsecurepassword.com/CommandLineRandomPasswordGenerator.aspx) (archived link). It has the follwing syntax:

```
gspk.exe /g [-l:password_length] [-a:charset_options]
```

Just to clarify: gspk.exe is the executable of a GUI program, but it can also be used in command line by calling it with arguments.

Comment: Read [this post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330), you must.

Comment: I tried this program in CLI, after execution it has to be terminated using Ctrl+C to get the prompt back, and more importantly, there seems to be no way to grab the output (e.g. to a file, and I did try `>output.txt 2>&1`), making the program quite useless in practice…

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell, it is now cross platform, you can download PowerShell 7 from GitHub. I can give you this simple code for this task. Notice: I have only tested my code on PowerShell 7, I guarantee my code will work, however I don't know if it will work on PowerShell 5.1.

The code:

```PowerShell
$randomstring=for ($i=0;$i -lt 100;$i++) {
    $choice=$(get-random -min 0 -max 99) % 2
    switch ($choice)
    {
        0 {[char]$(Get-Random -Min 65 -Max 90)}
        1 {[char]$(Get-Random -Min 97 -Max 122)}
    }
}
$randomstring=$randomstring -join ""
$randomstring
```

It will generate a random string of capital and small Latin letters with the length of 100 (100 total letters).

Sample output:

```PowerShell
GRTkSpLsUtigeJfpENKoyoFGeUSgbWDNIQKFmDeDldtsICSIdaFAfpkKikVmyLPNojQJwrwBTjSqygEUeJiaJNjVARhpHPUWDCYw
```

Now if you want to add symbols and numbers:

```PowerShell
[array]$symbols=@('+','-','*','/','?','\')
$randomstring=for ($i=0;$i -lt 100;$i++) {
    $choice=$(get-random -min 0 -max 99) % 4
    switch ($choice)
    {
        0 {[char]$(Get-Random -Min 65 -Max 90)}
        1 {[char]$(Get-Random -Min 97 -Max 122)}
        2 {$symbols[$(Get-Random -Min 0 -Max $($symbols.count-1))]}
        3 {$(Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 9)}
    }
}
$randomstring=$randomstring -join ""
$randomstring
```

Sample output:

```PowerShell
CoRWBjiphnfO3fXXvQaYS?JLGWISH?wRtn-P*nS-E*y8D?E53/E4?+?q7Kd-M//?2tl5t*gU*pHdqorL5/5a0wS6N3*2SvOx-ni8
```

Tweak as needed; If you want a shorter string, change the number 100 in `$i -lt 100` to the number you want. And if you want other symbols, put the symbol enclosed in quotes into the `[array]$symbols=@('+','-','*','/','?','\')` line, separate the symbols by comma;

Answer (score 0):

[deepsix](http://ericandresen.me/technology/deepsix/) will generate passwords (or many passwords) in the command line.

It is cross-platform developed in C and works on every platform I have tested it on, macOS, x86 & 64-bit Windows, and Linux. Just as you describe it offers `-cNumber` of Chars and `-iIterations` and at present offers uppercase, lowercase and numeric symbols.

I am currently adding password safe symbols in a 2.0 version - but 1.0c is available now, works locally, and does not require the Internet. It is a command-line tool, no GUI but that shouldn't be an issue. I posted the source code and several precompiled platform executables. Hopefully someone else benefits from this as I wanted one long enough I eventually wrote it myself.

Comment: So this is a software recommendation then, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ok late but it will be helpful. I hope.

TL:DR
So let me share it with you https://github.com/the-j0k3r/batch-101 and see about
Simple Password Generator

A long time ago I wrote a password generator, it allowed me to generate passwords with higher entropy than %random% (since %random% is not actually random at all) and of any length on Windows, it also allows to save passwords to a file with a reference for each password, so in theory you can keep that file on a external drive for easy reference and added security.